# Attempting to create a list(of list(of string))

Tags: vb.net, list, class, properties

I am attempting to create a list which contain a class with a list of arrays

Example: book(2).page(4).wordcount(1) = 4

so I create these:

```
Public Class plist
    Dim _wordcount As String = ""
    Public Property wordcount() As String
        Get
            Return _wordcount
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _wordcount = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
Public Class blist
    Dim _page As List(Of plist)
    Public Property page() As List(Of plist)
        Get
            Return _page
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of plist))
            _page = value
        End Se
    End Property
End Class
```

Then I create a list like so:

```
Dim Book as new list(of blist)
```

After that everything doesn't seem right

I can add a book:

```
Book.add(new blist)
```

but I get a null reference error adding a page:

```
Book(0).page.add(new plist)
```

I am probably totally off track here.  I would be very grateful if someone could put me on the right track.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Auto-implemented properties could reduce that boilerplate code to `Public Property Page As List(Of plist)` and initialize in the constructor (or declare them as `New`).  With more idiomatic naming: `Public Property PageList As List(Of Page)`  `plist` is kind of a grody class name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `page` Property backing field is currently:

`Dim _page As List(Of plist)`
which means that the list is never initialised.

It should be

`Dim _page As New List(Of plist)`

Comment: All I needed I guess was a fresh set of awake eyes.  Thank you.